# Setting up a basic cloud for documents using Java EE 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm planning to setup an Enterprise application where the Java standalone client can upload and download .doc and .odt documents from an application server (WildFly). I'm evaluating different solutions such as:

1. Using a Servlet as bridge to upload documents and download using an HttpConnection.
2. Using a REST Web service to upload and download the document
3. Using an EJB and passing the document as argument and returning the document from the EJB call

I think all of the above solutions should somehow work, but which is more fit for a Desktop application, which also needs some level of authentication during the communication?
Thanks

Comment: If you only want to offer access to the documents via your client application, REST would be a good solution.
If you think about having a WebUI too, Servlets would do the job.

Comment: I found Jersey to be a bit difficult to work with file uploads but you can try the apache fileupload project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree all of the above solutions should work, however instead of using plain Servlets, why not using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) libraries from Apache which make fairly simple to upload and download files ? There is even a library written on the top of HttpClient which is named [Awake file](http://www.awake-file.org/) which is opensource and allows secure upload and download of documents from Java Desktop applications and Android clients as well.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I managed to set up quickily Awake file. It seems quite interesting solution so I'll try it as first option.